# What's the difference between these two phrases?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

What's the difference between these two phrases?

> - their systems’ security posture
> - their systems security posture

Is there any difference in the meaning? If not, when we use either of them?

Comment: One's system is plural, possessive and grammatical, the other not.

Comment: @mplungjan: I disagree. They're both grammatical. One is possessive, the other could be said to use a "plural attributive noun". You might think such plural usage is at the very least "a bit unusual", but I don't think it's inherently "incorrect". Highly topical, actually, since tomorrow is [**Veterans Day**](http://www.arrantpedantry.com/2010/11/11/attributives-possessives-and-veterans-day/) - which is invariably pluralised, with no apostrophe.

Comment: If the second had been _their system's security posture_ it would have been singular and possessive. I do not see _their systems security posture_ being correct in any way. The veterans in _Veterans Day_ is an attributive adjective and not possessive or it should have been _Veterans' Day_

Comment: Hmm, reading the other answer, I will have to retract half my comment. "systems security posture" could be the title of a posture. I would expect it to be "system security posture" though

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "[...] their systems' security posture [...]" uses a possessive form to show that security posture quality belongs to the systems.

The phrase "[...] their systems security posture [...]" is using "systems security posture" as a noun phrase, as though "systems security posture" is a thing. This might be a matter of jargon, but I've not heard that expression before. Still, it almost certainly means the exact same thing as the first phrase.

Comment: The second one is just an example which I made to clarify the difference, because i can't understand when to use the possessive form.
e.g. "infrastructures' defense systems" or "infrastructures defense systems"?

Comment: I see. The possessive form is used to show that the noun that follows belongs to the person(s) whose name takes the possessive form. For example, If you want to talk about a baseball bat that belongs to John, you would say, "John's baseball bat [...]". If you didn't use the possessive form (no apostrophe), you'd be using a plural as "Johns", which means two or more Johns. :) Use the possessive form with apostrophe when you want to show a thing belongs to someone or something. Use the plural form when you want to show there are two or more of the thing.

Comment: In your example "John" is a person and it's clear that plural "Johns" doesn't make sense, but in my example "infrastructures" is plural in both forms, but I cant find whether it should be in possessive form or not

Comment: Let's take a simple noun, like "dog". If the dog has a toy, it's the "dog's toy". That's easy enough. If three dogs all share a toy, it's "the dogs' toy". That structure with the apostrophe after the "s" usually indicates plural possessive. In the case of your above example, then, the "s" + apostrophe on "systems'" indicates plural possessive, meaning the thing that follows belongs to two or more systems. Make sense?

Comment: I know how to use possessive form and its meaning. If we delete the "posture" then which one is correct? systems security or systems' security?

Comment: See my original answer. The possessive form is probably more technically correct, but both phrases communicate the same idea well enough that I doubt anyone would misunderstand either one.

Comment: Tanx. This question rises because we have for example "network security services" that (in my view) is similar to "system security posture" but it's not in possessive form, although there are some services which somehow belongs to network.

Comment: I see. There's nothing wrong with the phrase "network security services" as it is because "network security services" is all one big noun phrase. You can lump it all together and treat it all as one noun. The same is true of the second example in the question. In IT, though, the noun phrase "network security" is very commonly used, so stick with the non-possessive form. Just note that this is a case of _jargon_ and does not obey the standard rules of grammar.

Answer (score 0):

> their systems’ security posture

The security posture of their systems.

> their systems security posture

The 'systems security' posture of them (whoever 'they' are).